app restarting when I ask for permissions, permissions change
in my react native app when I ask an user for permissions (camera, recording) the app gets restartd and sometimes I lose the state on the proccess which can turn in some issues, is there a way to avoid this?
I tried with this code in my app.js but app always restarts, I would like to avoid refetching info again and losing current state data.
const getInitialInfoFromStore = async (isInitial = true) => 
    {
        // Your logic to fetch initial data
        if(permsChangedRecently())
        {
            return;
        }
        console.log('/////////////    FETCHING INFO    /////////////');
        root.uiStore.getDeviceDimensions();
        const today = moment().isoWeekday();
        root.mapStore.setIsoWeekDay(today);
        root.mapStore.listenInternetConnection();
        checkNotificationPermission();
        if(isInitial)
        {
            let results = await root.mapStore.requestLocationPermissions(0);
            console.log('RESULTS',results);
        }
        
        
        await root.userStore.getLoggedUser(root.userStore.userId,root.mapStore.isInitial);
    };


    const permsChangedRecently = (seconds = 1) =>
        {
            console.log('permissionsGrantedAt ***************************************', root.mapStore.permissionsGrantedAt);
        
            if (!root.mapStore.permissionsGrantedAt) {
                return false; // No permission time available
            } else {
                const currentTime = new Date();
                const timeElapsed = (currentTime - root.mapStore.permissionsGrantedAt) / 1000; // time elapsed in seconds
                console.log('timeElapsed',timeElapsed);
                // Check if timeElapsed is less than or equal to the given seconds
                return timeElapsed <= seconds;
            }
        };
        


    useEffect(() => {
        const appStateListener = AppState.addEventListener('change', nextAppState => {
          console.log('Next AppState is: ', nextAppState);
          setAppState(nextAppState);
          console.log('-------------------------CURRENT APP STATE ' + nextAppState + '----------------------------');
    
          if (nextAppState === 'active' && storesHydrated) {
            // Fetch data only when stores are rehydrated and app is active
            getInitialInfoFromStore(false);
          }
          else
          {
            let lastTimeScreenWasFocused = new Date().toISOString();;
            console.log('lastTimeScreenWasFocused ***************************************',lastTimeScreenWasFocused);
            root.mapStore.setLastTimeChatsScreenFocused(lastTimeScreenWasFocused);
          }
        });
    
        return () => {
          appStateListener?.remove();
        };
      }, [storesHydrated]); 


I don't know react native but the app should not restart when you ask for camera permission. are you sure you put the relevant permission in your android manifest file? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> 

And what is root? What module are you using to request permissions?

It actually restarts when I grant perms
